# Controlling the image size functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out the best way to control the image size of this. it's part of my functions.php page regarding email invoicing. how can I control the size of ' . $_product->get_image() . '...?

```
     <td style="text-align:left; padding: 3px;">' . $_product->get_image() . '</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has some nifty functions for specifying image sizes when you display them.

Specifically:

`add_image_size` [Codex for this function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

`wp_get_attachment_image` [Codex for this function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)

You'll want to use these two in tandem, you'll want to specify a new image size that fits your table cells perfectly in dimension, and then you're going to make a call to the second function in order to programmatically output the image at the size you specify with `add_image_size`

NOTE: When adding a new image size in functions.php, you'll have to use a plugin like [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) in order to get the newly defined image size for existing images.

So then, lets say we need 50x50 images for our table cells.

in functions.php:
`add_image_size('table-cell-dimensions', 50, 50, true);`

And when we need to apply it in our table, this should do the trick:

```
<td style="text-align:left; padding: 3px;">' . echo wp_get_attachment_image('image_id', 'table-cell-dimensions' . '</td>
```

The only assumption I'm making is that you have the attachment ID for these images you're using.

Comment: in this case it's a plugin for invoicing and it injects the table into the invoice sent out to the user. https://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201004747-PIP-Extension-add-product-images-to-invoice?locale=en-us[/link] so what I'm wondering is how to add code to control the size.